# Visual Studio 2015 Docker Integration wont attach for debuging

Tags: visual-studio, docker

I created a Default .net Core RC2 MVC app using VS 2015.  I added Docker Support so I could run and debug it in docker.

When I run the project it builds the docker container and starts it.  Running the command "docker ps" shows the container running with the correct ports mapped.  However I get the following error:

The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event.  Ensure that the target process is configured to use NETStandard [version ...] or newer.  This might be expected if the target process did not run.

[image]

Also trying to access the web page returns the following error:

[Fiddler] The connection to '10.0.75.2' failed. 
Error: ConnectionRefused (0x274d). 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.0.75.2:80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem is related to the docker for windows beta I am running.  By default it does not let you map volumes.

To enable open the docker for window settings:

[image: Docker for windows settings]

And select Manage shared drives.

Select the C drive or drive you have the .Net code stored on and rebuild and deploy the project:

[image: Docker settings with C share enabled]