# Debug on Docker throws an error

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I just created simple **DotNetCore** WebApi and added **Docker** support through **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** *(as latest as it can be)*.  Ran the debug on docker and following error occurred when I tried to debug it on docker.

> The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use Microsoft.NETCoreApp 1.0.0 or newer. This may be expected if the target process did not run .NET code.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

### Side notes

- [Latest SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=809122) is installed so message in **Debug output** doesn't make sense
- [Latest VS205 Tools for Docker Preview](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4) is installed
- Based on [Visual Studio 2015 Docker Integration wont attach for debuging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37446873/visual-studio-2015-docker-integration-wont-attach-for-debuging) drive C is checked under the Shared Drives of Docker Settings
- [GitHub Issue 4657](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/4657) does not help.

## Dockerfile.debug

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-core
```

## Debug output

```
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:CLRDBG_VERSION = "VS2015U2"
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:REMOTE_DEBUGGING = 0
VERBOSE: Executing: docker exec -i 64495b0eae7c /clrdbg/clrdbg --interpreter=mi
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from: 
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
The program '' has exited with code 145 (0x91).
```

## Docker output

```
C:\Users\kal-el\Documents\Visual` Studio` 2015\Projects\Krypton\src\Krypton\DockerTask.ps1 -Run -Environment Debug -Machine '' -RemoteDebugging $True -OpenSite $False
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:CLRDBG_VERSION = "VS2015U2"
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:REMOTE_DEBUGGING = 1
VERBOSE: Executing: docker-compose -f 'C:\Users\kal-el\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Krypton\src\Krypton\bin\Docker\Debug\app\docker-compose.Debug.yml' -p krypton up -d
Recreating krypton_krypton_1
C:\Users\kal-el\Documents\Visual` Studio` 2015\Projects\Krypton\src\Krypton\DockerTask.ps1 -WaitForUrl -Machine ''
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:CLRDBG_VERSION = "VS2015U2"
VERBOSE: Setting: $env:REMOTE_DEBUGGING = 0
Opening site http://docker ........................................................................................................................
Validating volume mapping in the container 64495b0eae7c
ValidateVolumeMapping : Unable to validate volume mapping. For troubleshooting, follow instructions from 
http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting
At C:\Users\kal-el\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Krypton\src\Krypton\DockerTask.ps1:352 char:9
+         ValidateVolumeMapping
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,ValidateVolumeMapping
```

> Question posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6475)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading [Docker Tools for Visual Studio 2015 - Preview](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4) to **v0.31.0** fixes the issue.